# Can't change viewController with button in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I am trying to open a new ViewController with a button click. I created a new secondViewController class and set the name to SecondViewController. I also added an Navigation Controller and connected it with the RootView Controller. However if I try to run it i get the following errors:[image]

```
   btn_Next.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>{

                secondViewController controller = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SecondViewController") as secondViewController;
                this.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);
            };
```

Did I miss something and is the Name the same thing like the Storyboard Id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you never created a separate class for your `secondViewController`.
Make sure you explicitly create a new `UIViewControlle`r class:

```
public partial class SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
}
```

Then in your storyboard, set the "Class" of your `secondViewController` to this class.

This will let you cast `InstantiateViewController` to your `SecondViewController`.

Alternatively, you can just change your code to this:

```
        btn_Next.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>{

            var controller = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SecondViewController");
            this.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);
        };
```

If you don't care for having a separate class for your new controller.

Comment: So I created the new UIViewController class, added the class to the secondViewController and instantiated the class as SecondViewController. However I still get the error that the SecondViewController can't be found. I specified with the name, but I can't find a way to set the storyboard id.

Comment: When you select the UIVeiwController while in your story board (by clicking the bottom margin), open up the properties tab, and there is a "Storyboard ID" field. Right under "Class" and "Module"

Comment: Oh, Thanks found it. I always created a UIView class a specified the view, so I couldn't see the "Storyboard id" property.